# Error with deleting cell row with button

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a button on each row that I want to delete the row it is in. My code is below. The last line below I am getting "cannot invoke"

```
@IBAction func deletebutton(sender: AnyObject) {

    let button = sender as! UIButton
    let view = button.superview!
    let cell = view.superview as! YourAdviseControllerCell

    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)

    let row = indexPath?.row

    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(NSIndexPath(forRow: row!, inSection: 0), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter type of the "deleteRowsAt**IndexPaths**:withRowAnimation:" is an **Array** not a **NSIndexPath**.

Try this:

```
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: row!, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
```